# Imagemagick "Flatten" frames in animated GIF while maintaining global color table

Tags: imagemagick

I have an animated GIF with a 256byte global color table. The later frames  do not extend to the full canvas dimensions so they "patch" over areas of canvas. Graphics on earlier layers are only partially obscured by graphics on later layers. My goal is to "flatten" the image so that I have a 1-frame/non-animated gif that appears as the animated GIF does on the final frame of its animation (after all its frames have been drawn). I can acheive the desired results with imagemagick:

```
convert animation.gif -flatten flattened.gif
```

This creates a single-frame GIF called flattened.gif that looks like animation.gif does on it's final frame. Great!

My problem is that flattened.gif has a different (incidentally smaller) global colour table. I have some unusual application-specific requirements that mean I need to keep the global color table of the flattened GIF identical to the global color table of the source, animated GIF.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try extracting the colours from the original GIF with `convert original.gif -unique-colors palette.gif` then applying that palette to the final image with `convert final.gif -remap palette.gif result.gif`. You may, or may not want dithering.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the colours from the original GIF and saving them as `palette.gif` using this command:

```
convert original.gif -unique-colors palette.gif
```

Then, when you have your final image, apply the original palette back to it with:

```
convert final.gif -remap palette.gif result.gif
```